# Why is my delegation showing as origination?

Tags: tzscan, delegating

I just did my first delegation of tezos. However, when I check the block of the baker (in TzScan), I can see my delegation not in the delegation list but in the origination's list. For instance (fake example), [this](https://tzscan.io/KT1NGvZVqoNse3gaqCFkpU8A5scBRd1cdrEn) is my delegation, which shows a "1" in originations:

[image]

If I go to the block explorer of the [baker](https://tzscan.io/tz1bkKTY9Y3rTsHbpr2fbGUCRm736LLquQfM?default=delegation), under tab delegations, I can see 12 delegations and 3 originations, the top one being mine.

Did I do something wrong in my delegation? Or does it take some time (7 cycles, it seems) to be listed in the delegation? If so, then why some originations are longer than ~20 days  (3 days a cycle times 7), e.g. [here](https://tzscan.io/tz3RB4aoyjov4KEVRbuhvQ1CKJgBJMWhaeB8?default=delegation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you originate a KT1, you can set a delegate. That is why we split the delegation tab in two sections :

- a delegation operation
- a delegation through an origination

Comment: To be sure, just go to your KT1 account and on the right column, you should see the delegate's tz1 under the balance.

Comment: I see myself (tz1...) listed as Manager and the baker's address as Delegate. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, so you should be fine.

Comment: So after a while it should show in the baker's explorer under delegation rather than originations?

Comment: It should already be in the delegation section. Look at the Delegators list, your KT1 should already be there.

Comment: You need to go to the baker's delegation tab, not yours since you didn't make a delegation operation but an origination.